# Is ZF${}-{}$(Axiom of Infinity) consistent?

Tags: set-theory

Godel's theorem implies that Con(ZF) is not provable in ZF since it contains the axiom of infinity.

So is it consistent if the Axiom of infinity is removed?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set

Comment: Well obviously if ZF is consistent then any subtheory is consistent, since you can't make an inconsistent theory consistent by adding more premises... Unless you're wondering if $\mathsf{ZF+\neg Inf}$ can prove its own consistency?

Comment: @Malice I have not studied set theory seriously. Let's call the set theory with all axioms of ZF without Axiom of infinity, T. Is Con(T) provable under T?

Comment: I will not give this as an answer, because I do not know enough to formulate it correctly, but ZF-Inf is as good as PA, and the incompleteness theorem applies to PA. So ZF can prove Con(ZF-Inf) (compare Hurkyl's comment), but if ZF-Inf is consistent then ZF-Inf cannot prove Con(ZF-Inf).

Comment: The first sentence is incorrect. That Con(ZF) is not provable in ZF has nothing to do with the axiom of infinity. Perhaps you are thinking that the axiom of infinity allows us to interpret arithmetic? You need to clarify what you mean. If this is what you mean, ZF without the axiom of infinity also interprets arithmetic, so the axiom of infinity is not relevant to the discussion.

Comment: The second sentence makes no sense. I mean, the first sentence (ignoring its problems) only makes sense if we assume the consistency of ZF. But then the second sentence follows trivially. Perhaps what you mean to ask is whether ZF can *prove* the consistency of ZF without the axiom of infinity? If that is the case, the answer is yes. This has been asked a few times on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZF with the negation of Infinity and Peano arithmetic are mutually interpretable. Richard Kaye and Tin Lok Wong's paper *On interpretations of arithmetic and set theory* has one of the classic expositions of how to interpret finite ZF in PA, and vice versa; Quine's *Set Theory and its Logic* also has a nice detailed exposition on getting Peano arithmetic without any infinite sets. But the consequence is that if finite ZF could prove its own consistency, it would imply that PA could prove its own consistency, which is not the case.

Comment: Once has the stronger claim that ZF-Infinity+$\lnot$Infinity and PA are bi-interpretable.

Comment: Yeah, Kaye-Wong does involve that stronger claim; but I don't think the original poster needs to be too concerned with that (unless they want to be). The paper is still the best brief introduction to the Ackermann interpretation I've seen, and it's mostly in that capacity that I mention it.

Comment: This is a classical result, not due to Kaye and Wong. The concepts of mutual interpretability and bi-interpretability are rarely introduced separately, so only mentioning the weaker statement looks strange.

Comment: I posted the weaker as I understand (hopefully correctly?) it's adequate to answer the original question. If you would really recommend mention in the answer rather than just in your comment I will make that alteration. (Also I was not intending to attribute historical primacy to Kaye and Wong.)

Comment: For the purpose of answering the question, what you are saying is correct and suffices, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is unclear.

It is true that $\sf ZF$ cannot prove its own consistency. But $\sf ZF$ can prove the consistency of $\sf ZF-Infinity$, simply by verifying that the set of hereditarily finite sets satisfies all the axioms of $\sf ZF$ except the axiom of infinity.

This set, often denoted by $HF$ or $V_\omega$ can be defined as follows, $V_0=\varnothing, V_{n+1}=\mathcal P(V_n)$, and $V_\omega=\bigcup V_n$. Note that all the elements of $V_\omega$ are finite, and their elements are finite and so on.

On the other hand, if you want to ask whether or not $\sf ZF-Infinity$ proves its own consistency, then the answer is no. The reason is that this theory satisfies the requirements of the incompleteness theorem, and therefore cannot prove its own consistency (unless it is inconsistent to begin with).