# Proving infinity vs Axiom of infinity

Tags: set-theory

I am not much of a set theorist, I deal primarely with algebra in my interest and what I study so this is toward set theorists. I am curious as to why cannot infinity be properly proven to exist? I know this is the issue which makes it be an axiom in ZFC set theory but I'd like to know in a more rigorous sense why it is not possible to prove it in any meaningful sense, it is intuitively relatively simple I feel but I'd like the formal one.

A link or description here would be in an equivalence class of acceptance ;-P

Comment: "$\omega_0$ is the most unreachable ordinal" Quote from my set theory lecturer last year.

Comment: that does not really answer it in any meaningful fashion =/

Comment: You changed it! :P Well maybe link to the lecture if it's recorded or written?

Comment: No, he just said it in passing. But the idea is that none of the other axioms can take a finite set and construct an infinite one. Therefore you have to stipulate its existence as an axiom. We never went into details on it, but I would think that $R(\omega_0)$ satisfies all the other axioms, which by Gödel's incompleteness theorem proves that the existence of $\omega_0$ is unprovable.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/677097/1284

Comment: You will need an axiom of infinity or equivalent that postulate the existence of some infinite set, or some Peano-like axioms to start with.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The phrase "infinity cannot be properly proven to exist" begs the question: what axioms are we allowed to use to 'properly prove' something? Some sets of axioms, of course, can prove that an infinite set exists - e.g., ZFC :P. Others can't - e.g., ZFC minus the axiom of infinity (this is a good exercise - checking that the set $V_\omega$ of hereditarily finite sets is a model of all the ZFC axioms *except* Infinity). (We can also find reasonable-sounding sets of axioms which do prove the existence of an infinite set, but don't obviously sound like they do; so you have to be careful here. For example, Quine's New Foundations NF - see my and Zhen Lin's comments below.)

The axioms of ZFC are formulated to build the universe of sets starting from the smallest possible ingredient - the emptyset, $\emptyset$. In one interpretation, the axioms come in three flavors:

- "Contextual" axioms, Foundation and Extensionality. These don't help us build new sets, they tell us what sort of object a set *is*.
- "Toolbox" axioms - Union, Pairing, Powerset, Separation, Replacement, and Choice. These are axioms which - more or less - tell us how to build new sets from old sets. (The "more or less" applies to Powerset and Choice, which don't really tell you *how* to build the new set, but whatever.) I ought to catch a transfinite amount of flack for grouping all these axioms together, but for this question I think this is the right grouping to uses.
- And then you have the "Jack-in-the-box" axioms - that just give you a set ex nihilo, that you otherwise couldn't build using the toolbox. In ZFC, there's only one - Infinity. But we often consider other similar axioms - we call them "strong axioms of infinity," or **large cardinals**.

The reason Infinity has to be a jack-in-the-box is that, if we start with the emptyset, then all our toolbox axioms just keep spitting out finite sets. So we have a "gap" between the finite and the infinite.

Comment: And then there are set theories where infinite sets come for free – NF, for instance.

Comment: @ZhenLin Quite right. I would have listed that as an example of the last sentence in my first paragraph, but I think it *is* obvious why NF proves the existence of an infinite set. (NF is, however, a *fantastic* example of a theory which nonobviously disproves choice.)

Comment: Is it obvious? My impression is that NF proves infinite sets exist because NF refutes choice.

Comment: @ZhenLin The formula "$x=x$" is stratified, so you get a universal set.

Comment: @ZhenLin Wait, you're absolutely right - it's not obvious how to show that the universal set is infinite! In fact, we can't - NFU is consistent with "All sets are finite." I've edited my answer.

Comment: I would not call them "Jack-in-the-box". As I understand, what happens is one thinks "Okay, I have these axioms. What sets can I build using them? Now, let's call this collection of sets a set as well". So, one calls this a new axiom and continues to build new sets using it. The axiom did not suddenly jump on us out-of-the-blue, but it was totally natural and expected result of this process.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about things like ZF, then you're working in that context and that context is not everything.  The class of all hereditarily finite sets is a model of ZF without the axiom of infinity.  Therefore ZF without the axiom of infinity is consistent with every set being finite.

Comment: This is not true - $ZF$ includes the axiom of infinity. So $ZF-Inf$ is consistent with everything being finite, but $ZF$ is not.

Comment: It is not just that the hereditarily finite sets model ZF without infinity, but that, moreover, they also satisfy the statement "every set is finite". (Obviously, all members of the class HF of hereditarily finite sets are finite, but this is weaker than the above, and we typically need to invoke some absoluteness to get the needed statement.)

Answer (score 0):

We prove that Vω is a model of ZF - infinity, that only proves that ZF-infinity is consistent. To prove that in ZF-Infinity we can't prove the consistency of the existence of an Infinite set, suppose it is consistent with ZF-Infinity (I'll call I=Infinity and X=exists infinite set). Then Con(ZF-I)-->Con((ZF-I)+X). Suppose (ZF-I)+X is consistent. Then there is a model K of it, there we can construct Vω, so we proved Con(ZF-I), therefore (ZF-I)+X proves Con((ZF-I)+X) which is impossible due to Godels Incompleteness theorem.